# compare date in sql statement

Tags: javascript, sql, web-sql, date-comparison

I am making an alert tool using web sql.

I want to selects all events that occur in a specific day. when I insert the event I insert the date as a date object with this format "2011-10-14" , **What should I write in select statement to select all events that occur today ?**

I make like this

```
 cur =new Date();
alert(cur);
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("select NOTE_DESC,NOTE_DATE,NOTE_TIME,ALERT_TIME,NOTES_MORE_DETAILS from NOTES where NOTE_DATE = "+cur+" order by NOTE_TIME asc limit 0,1",[], alert("yes"),onError);
});
```

In which my query is:

```
select NOTE_DESC, NOTE_DATE, NOTE_TIME, ALERT_TIME, NOTES_MORE_DETAILS 
from NOTES 
where NOTE_DATE = "+cur+" 
order by NOTE_TIME asc 
limit 0,1
```

but an error message occur which is "near Oct: syntax error"

How should I make the date comparison in sql ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
NOTE_DATE = '"+cur.getFullYear()+'-'+(cur.getMonth()+1)+'-'+cur.getDate()+"'
```

Note the `'` wrapping the value for the query variable, and calling the `cur` date object's methods to construct the date.

http://jsfiddle.net/yXgDw/

Better yet, use a prepared query:

http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-sqltransaction-executesql

http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#introduction

Comment: It works when I make like this cur.getFullYear()+'-'+(cur.getMonth()+1)+'-'+cur.getDate()

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was wondering why they weren't reporting correctly. `:)`

Comment: Can you update your answer with code in the comment to make it easier for other developers who may face the same problem :)

Comment: I did, at least I think I did?